Different number of levels of a nested factor within the primary factor ANOVA
I'm struggling with understanding how or if I can use permanova (within vegan::adonis2()) to analyze a data set that has 3 levels of a "treatment", but different numbers of levels of a nested factor within each treatment. I've tried reviewing the permute vignette and Baaker's online book but I can't quite tell if I have an issue or not.
The response is presence/absence of parasite species in an aquatic critter, and we're interested in understanding if the severity of an invasive species influences the parasite community. There are 3 levels of a treatment or invaded-ness "status" (hi, med, low). A varying number of lakes falling within each category were found (2,6,4) and within each, 27 specimens were collected from each lake.
Lakes are nested within "treatment", but when I try to use the following as a constraint on the permutations I get an error about needing a balanced design.
CTRL<-how(within=Within(type='free'),
          plots=Plots(strata=my.covs$lake,type='free'))

Is this just an issue with how I am defining strata? Is there some clever way of recoding the data such that gets around this or is a permanova not feasible with this design? Is it something I can manually permute? My, probably incorrect, understanding is that to test the effect of "treatment" (i.e., MS Treatment/ MS lake(treatment)) my exchangeable unit is the lake, and I thought just randomly reassigning lakes (and their 27 observations) to "treatments" was what I wanted to do, but it sounds like that's not true or not what I was specifying with the above code? If not, what is the correct way to handle this structure?

Assuming that there actually are 27 (or some multiple thereof) rows of data per lake, I don't see why there is imbalance? Is lake a factor?
Your how is wrong by the way. If the treatment varies at the level of lake and therefore is constant within the levels of lake, you shouldn't be permuting the samples within the lake strata. What you'd want is:
ctrl <- how(
  within = Within(type = "none"),
  plots  = Plots(strata = lake, type = "free")
)


Thanks, Gavin!
Based on my understanding, the F statistic and associated p-value for the main effect of treatment still needs to be corrected, as the output gives the F as being MS trt/ MS resid. Is this something I can do by hand (calculate the F)? If I wanted the correct P value, should I pull the SS/df from each iteration of the permutation and compute the  pseudo F's for the treatment effect myself?

@tlyons253 If there is an issue (there is in the computation of the pseudo F, but whether that's an issue is the question) is unclear. I think the book you refer to is wrong - the difference they observe in the example is purely floating point noise and not a problem more generally. Marti Anderson has posted claims that we get the wrong answer but as I have pointed out in several places now, Marti incorrectly specieifed the permutation design and thus no wonder the p value was wrong. We all accept the pesudo F is not right but does that matter? Perhaps, but we are still checking

Ok-I did test it by running permutations manually (https://uw.pressbooks.pub/appliedmultivariatestatistics/chapter/restricting-permutations/)
-the p-value is the same, even if F statistic is different. It sounds like that's what you expect, but because of my lack of a strong understanding of statistical theory, my reaction is "how neat is that", haha.
Thanks for the help!

@tlyons253 Thanks; That is what Jari and I suspected as we're just talking about an order statistic and we do the same thing to compute each permuted pseudo F. But we do want to check a broader range of examples to understand the behaviour. It also isn't outside the realm of possibility that we implement handling of nested terms (we state we don't support proper nested effects) but that will take more time.
